# Is there any rule in Islam that without my parents acceptance I can't convert to Islam?

Tags: sharia, conversion

I want to convert to Islam and the biggest problem for me is my parents they will never accept my decision. Is there any rule in Islam that without my parents acceptance I can't convert to Islam?

If there is a rule, are there any exceptions or any way round it?

Comment: We have enjoined on man kindness to parents; but if they strive to make thee join with Me that of which thou hast no knowledge, then obey them not. Unto Me is your return and I shall tell you what ye used to do.29:8

Comment: There is no rule in islam that you cannot convert without the parents acceptance, however you should take advice from someone you trust(preferably someone who had a similar experience) on how and when to tell you parents and family about your decision.

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum, Praise to Allah who instated faith in you. There has been a similar issue in the following question: [I want to convert, but I have family issue](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/i-want-to-convert-but-i-have-family-issue/8107#8107). If your situation is in any way dissimilar to it, please add more details in your question. The community will try to answer Insha Allah

Answer (score 3):

If you have faith and believe in Islam you should revert to Islam as so as possible because you don't know how long you have left in this dunya (world). If your parent are not happy with your decision and they do not want to revert too, then you will have to just keep encouraging them to convert by telling them what Islam is really about. I know some non-Muslims hate Muslims and wouldn't even want to listen to the truth. If this is the case then you should just revert by reciting the Shahadah which is the first pillar of Islam and states *“there is no god but Allah, and Muhammad is the messenger of Allah”*

> لَا إِلٰهَ إِلَّا الله مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُولُ الله
>
> lā ʾilāha ʾillā-llāh, muhammadun rasūlu-llāh

Allah has told us many times that we should obey our parents and keep them happy. However, we have also been told we should not do as we are told if it is against Islam.

> We have enjoined on man kindness to parents: but if they (either of them) strive (to force) thee to join with Me (in worship) anything of which thou hast no knowledge, obey them not. Ye have (all) to return to me, and I will tell you (the truth) of all that ye did. (Qur'an: Surah 29, Verse 8)

Each person will have to speak for themselves on the day of judgement and if you have been blessed and guided on the right path yet you do not revert because of your family, this will be regarded as a sin. However if your parents decide to revert too, then you will be rewarded more.

My advice to you would be that you should try to get yourself at a Mosque as soon as possible. There will be an Imam who will be happy to give you advice and help you revert. There is no need to worry, you will get all the support you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your parents permission to convert. In fact it is obligatory to convert even if they don't want you to.

As for your family issues, you should use Altakia, which is hiding your belief from your family. You can even lie (regarding your islam issue).

Answer (score 1):

> **وَ وَصَّيْنَا الْإِنْسانَ بِوالِدَيْهِ حُسْناً وَ إِنْ جاهَداكَ لِتُشْرِكَ بي‏ ما لَيْسَ لَكَ بِهِ عِلْمٌ فَلا تُطِعْهُما إِلَيَّ
>   مَرْجِعُكُمْ فَأُنَبِّئُكُمْ بِما كُنْتُمْ تَعْمَلُونَ**
>
> We have enjoined man to be good to his parents. **But if they urge you
>   to ascribe to Me as partner that of which you have no knowledge, then
>   do not obey them**. To Me will be your return, whereat I will inform you
>   concerning that which you used to do.(29:8)

If you were walking in a way in which there were a deep well and you were 100% sure that you were getting closer and closer to the well by taking each and every step, would you even take it seriously and follow accordingly if your parents wanted you to close your eyes and go on walking down the way without any resistance?

In this regard Imam Ali ibn Abi Talib has said:

> **No creature should be obeyed so long as such obedience means disobedience of the Creator** (Nahjul-Balagha, selection 165)